# Hanging indent for bibliography items

Tags: indentation

Just wondering, how would I reproduce this indentation formalism for certain scientific Journals:

[image]

Currently for the following LaTeX input

```
Draine, B. T., 2003, ARA\&A, 41, 241\\
Dufour, R. J. 1984, in IAU Symp. 108, Structure and Evolution of the Magellanic
Clouds, ed. S. van den Bergh \& K. S. de Boer (Dordrecht: Reidel), 353\\
Fitzpatrick, E. L., 1986, AJ, 92 , 1068\\
Fitzpatrick, E. L., 1999, PASP, 111, 63\\
```

I am seeing this:

[image]

Would be nice to see a little indentation going on for the Dufour reference. Any pro tips would be warmly welcomed!

Comment: It's really not ideal to format bibliography elements by hand. You should use `natbib`+`bibtex` or `biblatex`+`biber`. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702) for the differences and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5105) and [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13513).  If you insist on doing this manually, you should at least use the `bibliography` and `\bibitem` syntax that is standard with LaTeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn Hi Alan. Of course yes it would be much easier, but I'm writing a very small article to be aimed at undergraduates so it was a little easier for me to copy and paste references is as needed.

Comment: ok. So then use the `hanging` package.

Answer (score 12):

#### Disclaimer

Please note (for others who may read this) that this is *not* the recommended way to format a bibliography, but in a pinch, it does what you want.

#### Manually creating hanging paragraphs

The `hanging` package provides a `hangparas` environment that can do what you want. Notice I've removed the trailing `\\` from your code. `\\` should not be used to create new paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\begin{document}
\begin{hangparas}{.25in}{1}
Draine, B. T., 2003, ARA\&A, 41, 241

Dufour, R. J. 1984, in IAU Symp. 108, Structure and Evolution of the Magellanic Clouds, ed. S. van den Bergh \& K. S. de Boer (Dordrecht: Reidel), 353

Fitzpatrick, E. L., 1986, AJ, 92 , 1068

Fitzpatrick, E. L., 1999, PASP, 111, 63
\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Wonderful. I wasted full one day to ponder the idea of putting bibliography with hanging second line. I failed. But succeeded with hangpara command. Thanks

Comment: And what *is* the recommended way?

Comment: @A4L You should store your references in a `.bib` file and use a bibliography package like `natbib` or `biblatex` to do the formatting. See my comments on the question.