# Certain style in bibliography, but I'm writing sources as normal text

Tags: bibliographies, margins

I want to have my bibliography the way as in the picture, but I am not using a bibliography package, I just write the sources as text. How can I fix so that row 2 of every source has another left margin than row 1 of the same source (just like the picture)? Thank you!

This is an example of how my code looks like:

```latex
\noindent Marhavilas, P. K., Koulouriotis, D., Gemeni, V. (2011), "Risk analysis and assessment methodologies in the work sites: On a review, classification and comparative study of the scientific literature of the period 2000-2009", \textit{Journal of Loss Prevention in the Process Industries}, Vol. 24, No. 5, pp. 477-523.
\vspace{2mm}

\noindent Mentzer, J.T., DeWitt, W., Keebler, J.S., Min, S., Nix, N.W., Smith, C.D., Zacharia, Z.G. (2001), “Defining Supply Chain Management”, \textit{Journal of Business Logistics}, Vol. 22, No. 2, pp. 1-25.
\vspace{2mm}

\noindent Meredith, J. (1998), Building operations management theory through case and field research, \textit{Journal of Operations Management}, Vol. 16, pp. 441-54.
```

[image]

Comment: Although I'd personally suggest to give a bibliography management package such as `biblatex` a try, you could ,if you insist on a manual bibliography, use the `hanging` package as described by Alan Munn [in the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288209/134144) to a very similar question.

Comment: even if you are not using bibtex or biblatex you should at least mark up the bibliography using a `thebibliography` environment and `\bibitem` so that you get the layout and can use `\cite` to reference entries.

Comment: also if you want to do it by hand, use `--` to indicate a page range.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate the importance of posting a `Minimal Working Example` and not a snippet.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent Marhavilas, P. K., Koulouriotis, D., Gemeni, V. (2011), ``Risk analysis and assessment methodologies 
in the work sites: On a review, classification and comparative study of the scientific 
literature of the period 2000-2009", 
\textit{Journal of Loss Prevention in the Process Industries}, Vol. 24, No. 5, pp. 477--523.

\vspace{2mm}

\noindent Mentzer, J.T., DeWitt, W., Keebler, J.S., Min, S., Nix, N.W., Smith, C.D., 
Zacharia, Z.G. (2001), ``Defining Supply Chain Management'', 
\textit{Journal of Business Logistics}, Vol. 22, No. 2, pp. 1--25.

\vspace{2mm}

\noindent Meredith, J. (1998), Building operations management theory through 
case and field research, \textit{Journal of Operations Management}, Vol. 16, pp. 441--454.
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

unlike what you shown.

Comment: OP explicitly said they were trying to get the image shown, and were asking how to do that.