# Writing a bibliography, spacing

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm trying to manually create a bibliography. I have 2 questions.

**1. ALA formatting question**

This is the code:

> Hwang, David Henry. 1988. \textit {M. Butterfly.} https://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/gillespie17/files/2017/10/Hwang-David-Henry-M-Butterfly.pdf.

and this is how it turned out:
[image]

I need each source to be formatted more appropriately to ALA standards, where the second, third, v.v. line of the source is indented, like so:
[image]

How can I do this?
Please explain like I'm five as I'm fairly new to LaTeX.

**2. Why is it overrunning the border?**

This is how it looks:
[image]

How can I stop the overrun? It's happening with several sources in the list.

Comment: To typeset URLs load the `url` or `hyperref` package and use the `\url` command: `\url{https://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/gillespie17/files/2017/10/Hwang-David-Henry-M-Butterfly.pdf}`. LaTeX is only able to break URLs correctly if you mark the URL up as such. (It may happen that the URL still does not break nicely even if you use `\url` because by default that command only allows breaks in certain positions, in that case the package `xurl` may help, which allows breaks everywhere.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point 1.**

You can find a very good solution here: [Hanging indent for bibliography items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288205/hanging-indent-for-bibliography-items) (anyway pay attention to the disclaimer!)

Here is a different (and very elementary) solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{url}

\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}
\newenvironment{referencelist}{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}
    \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}
    }}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}     
  \begin{referencelist}
    \item Hwang, David Henry. 1988. \textit {M. Butterfly.} 
    \url{https://macaulay.cuny.edu/eportfolios/gillespie17/files/2017/10/Hwang-David-Henry-M-Butterfly.pdf.}
  \end{referencelist}
\end{document}
```

**Point 2.**

You need the `url` package and `\ulr` command. If even with this you do not get the desired result, you must find a "manual" solution which depends on the specific case.