# Indent for individual section of references

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

do anyone know how to get indent on only on section in LaTeX. Like this in word:[image]

I only want it for my references at the end without having to make a bibliography.

```
\begin{document}

\section{references}

Marshall, J., $\&$ Plumb, R. A. (2013). \emph{Atmosphere, ocean and climate dynamics: an introductory text.} Academic Press.
ISO 690 \\

IPCC, 2022: \emph{Climate Change 2022: Impacts, Adaptation, and Vulnerability.} Contribution of Working Group II to the Sixth Assessment Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change [H.-O. Pörtner, D.C. Roberts, M. Tignor, E.S. Poloczanska, K. Mintenbeck, A. Alegría, M. Craig, S. Langsdorf, S. Löschke, V. Möller, A. Okem, B. Rama (eds.)]. Cambridge University Press. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK and New York, NY, USA, 3056 pp., doi:10.1017/9781009325844.\\

Houghton, J. (2015). \emph{Global warming: the complete briefing.} Cambridge university press.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! The answer to your question depends on how you've made the references (aka bibliography). So to help us to help you, please extend your code snippet to a [minimal working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: Oh thank you! Although, I was hoping I was able to do it without "making a bibliography".

Comment: You might then be interested by the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288209/184389). However, as stated in it, creating a bibliography and using the `natbib` package is still a better way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for - thank you! Next time I'll create a bibliography :)